# jquery select element has property

Tags: jquery, select, properties

I need add event to all input have min or max value for validate them.

here is HTML code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" maxlength="60" />
<input type="text" min="13" placeholder="age" maxlength="2" />
<input type="text" max="99" placeholder="count" maxlength="2" />
```

and my js :

```
$("input(-----)").blur(function (){
        console.log($(this).val());
        // validate
    });
```

If I want to validate 2 last input select with has max or min property, what is my code replace with `(-----)` in js?

note: I test `input:min,input:max` and `$("input").has('min')` but I can't.
note2: I know can select if know min or max value for example `$("input[min='13']")` but i don't know what is the min or max value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[min], input[max]").blur(function (){
    console.log($(this).val());
    // validate
});
```

This will find `input` elements which have a `min` or `max` attribute of any value.